# Is there an easy way to peel garlic?

Tags: peeling

Is cooking garlic is the important part of **curry**.This huge use of **garlic** in our dishes wants the easy method to peel of **garlic**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this helps, but according to [Food Network site](https://www.foodnetwork.com/fn-dish/2012/11/peel-garlic-in-a-flash)

> Smashing whole garlic cloves is the best way to peel them: Place the cloves on a cutting board, hold the flat side of a chef's knife on top and give it a firm whack with the heel of your other hand. Use just enough force to split the skin and crack open the cloves; if you pulverize the garlic with a heavy-handed thud, it will be harder to peel.